# Adding memory to jvm

Tags: java, api, memory, jvm

Seeking for an explaination for my problem of jvm memory.
I added yesturday ram for my computer (total = 3GB).
I'm executing this instruction on the cmd: java -Xms2g
An error message is given as follows

[image: cmd screen scraping]

I would like to increase the heap memory of jvm in order to use an api which requires at least 2GB. Please help..

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit JVM ? (32 bit application cannot address more than 2Gb ram on windows and some of those 2Gb is needed by the runtime, libraries, etc.)

Comment: 32-bit Java 6 throws this, 64-bit Java 7 does not.

Comment: On 32-bit windows, the limit is closer to 1.3 GB of memory. (You will find a similar limit if you run excel on a large spreadsheet) If you need to access more memory in a single application, you need a 64-bit OS. 32-bit Java on 64-bit OSes can access up to 3 GB, but you are likely to be better off using the 64-bit JVM in that case.

Comment: Which version of Windows is this on? You're going to struggle if this is still a 32-bit MSFT OS.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Chris's answer.

If you are on 32 bit OS, the maximum value is between 1.5 to 1.8 GB. On 64 bits, you do not need to worry about the limit - it is very high.

Comment: I'm running a 32bit jvm. Have you then a suggestion about the way to use this api which needs at least 2GB ?

Comment: You simply cannot use more than this limit. If you have 64bits OS, then use 64 bits JVM.

Comment: I tryed this command which also falis: java -Xms1.5g -Xmx1.8g.

Comment: those are the maximum possible values so the actual value may be less so you have to reduce it until it works

Answer (score 3):

The command you show is setting the min heap size (Xms) not the max heap size (Xmx). It's failing because you must not have 2 GB of **free** memory on your system. When you start the JVM with -Xms2g it will immediately try to claim 2GB of memory. If it cannot, then it will give you the error you displayed.

Comment: Even the -Xmx2g fails. What to do?

Comment: again, it's limited by how much free memory you actually have. Run your task manager (on windows) or top (on linux/osx) and look to see how much memory is free. Your Xmx value must be less than that.